# how to update Expandable Listview with new items?(notifyDataSetChanged()not works)

Tags: android, android-edittext, expandablelistview

I have expandable Lisview and i load the data to listview from server.

And there are some rows with edittext. so whenever i pressed right button for edit, 
edittext is focusable and edit that value and again pressed on that button value will goes to sever.

But from this it did not save it,Its again restore original value.
But when i am refreshing same activity value got changed.

How to load the Expandable listview with new editable values?

Here is my Code:-This is my activity

```
public class EditSwitch1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


ExpandableListAdapter1 listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private TextView edit_text;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
private TextView back;
private String roomId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_editswitch1);
    pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(EditSwitch1Activity.this);
    editor = pref.edit();
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

    back = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.back);
    expListView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
    // preparing list data

    Window window = EditSwitch1Activity.this.getWindow();
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(EditSwitch1Activity.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_statusbar));


    roomId = getIntent().getStringExtra("roomId");
    String serverURL = "http://dashboard.droidhomes.in/api/module?room_id=" + roomId;

    // Use AsyncTask execute Method To Prevent ANR11 Problem
    new LongOperation1().execute(serverURL);


    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();


    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });


}

private class LongOperation1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    // Required initialization

    // private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    private String Content;
    private String Error = null;

    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(
            EditSwitch1Activity.this);
    String data = "";

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

        //Dialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        //Dialog.show();

        //         data += "Authorization:eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Ijk5MjEyMzQ4MTMiLCJyb2xlIjoiY3VzdG9tZXIiLCJpZCI6IjU4M2VhZjI0OWM1ZDM5MTgyMzk0MTkzNyIsIm5hbWUiOiJWaWpheSBNYWxob3RyYSJ9.aF-vgNvOSSk_mbi_cTGufG2JZRrmP38zPFGn9UK9iMA";
    }

    // Call after onPreExecute method
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {

        /************ Make Post Call To Web Server ***********/
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        // final String ALLOWED_URI_CHARS = "@#&=*+-_.,:!?()/~'%";
        // String urlEncoded = Uri.encode(path, ALLOWED_URI_CHARS);
        // Send data
        try {

            // Defined URL where to send data

            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);

            // Send POST data request

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            //conn.setDoOutput(true);
            String auth_token = pref.getString("auth_token", "");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", auth_token);
            //conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            //byte[] encodedPassword = ( "Authorization" + ":" + "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Ijk5MjEyMzQ4MTMiLCJyb2xlIjoiY3VzdG9tZXIiLCJpZCI6IjU4M2VhZjI0OWM1ZDM5MTgyMzk0MTkzNyIsIm5hbWUiOiJWaWpheSBNYWxob3RyYSJ9.aF-vgNvOSSk_mbi_cTGufG2JZRrmP38zPFGn9UK9iMA" ).getBytes();
            //BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();

            // Get the server response

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            // Read Server Response
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Append server response in string
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            // Append Server Response To Content String
            Content = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Error = ex.getMessage();
        } finally {
            try {

                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }

        /*****************************************************/
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

        // Close progress dialog
        // Content=Content.replaceAll("<string>","");
        // Content=Content.replaceAll("</string>", "");
        Dialog.dismiss();

        if (Error != null) {

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Bad request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            // uiUpdate.setText("Output : " + Error);

        } else {

            // Show Response Json On Screen (activity)
            // uiUpdate.setText(Content);

            /****************** Start Parse Response JSON Data *************/

            // String OutputData = "";
            // JSONObject jsonResponse;

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            // Map messageObjMap = new Gson().fromJson(Content, Map.class);
            // String type = messageObjMap.get("messageType").toString();

            // Song song = gson.fromJson(message, Song.class);

            final SearchResponse response = gson.fromJson(Content,
                    SearchResponse.class);

            if (response.getStatus() == true) {


                List<String> newlist = new ArrayList<String>();


                for (int i = 0; i < response.getModule().length; i++) {


                    listDataHeader.add(response.getModule()[i].getModule_name());
                    newlist = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int j = 0; j < response.getModule()[i].getNo_of_switches(); j++) {

                        if (response.getModule()[i].getModuleId().getModuleid().equals(response.getModule()[i].getSwitches()[j].getModuleId().getModuleid())) {


                            newlist.add(response.getModule()[i].getSwitches()[j].getSwitch_name());


                        }


                        listDataChild.put(response.getModule()[i].getModule_name(), newlist);


                    }


                }


                listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter1(EditSwitch1Activity.this, listDataHeader, listDataChild, response);

                // setting list adapter
                expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "status:-" + response.getStatus(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }

    }

}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}
```

}

Also Attched the Expandable Listview Adapater:-

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter1 extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private String childText;
private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
private ArrayList<String> newlist;
private ArrayList<String> newlist1;
ArrayList<String>list1;
private SearchResponse response;
private Boolean onclick = true;

public ExpandableListAdapter1(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                              HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData, SearchResponse response) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    this.response = response;


}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtListChild.setText(childText); // Here whatever you will type in edittext will be overwritten by the value of 'childText.getTotal'. So after you are done writing in edit text make sore you change that in "_listDataChild" list.


    newlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    newlist1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list1=new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(childText);
    final TextView txtListChild1 = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.flash1);





    txtListChild1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (onclick) {

                txtListChild1.setText("Save");
                holder.txtListChild.setEnabled(true);
                onclick = false;
            } else {

                //  ArrayList<String> itemList=new ArrayList<String>();
                //itemList.add();
                onclick = true;
                txtListChild1.setText("Edit");
                holder.txtListChild.setEnabled(false);
                newlist.add(response.getModule()[groupPosition].getSwitches()[childPosition].getSwitchId().getId());
                newlist1.add(holder.txtListChild.getText().toString());
                String url = "http://dashboard.droidhomes.in/api/switch";
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(_context);
                JSONObject dataObj = new JSONObject();
                try {

                    JSONArray cartItemsArray = new JSONArray();
                    JSONObject cartItemsObjedct;
                    for(int i=0;i<newlist.size();i++){

                        cartItemsObjedct = new JSONObject();
                        cartItemsObjedct.putOpt("switch_id", newlist.get(i));
                        cartItemsObjedct.putOpt("switch_name",newlist1.get(i));
                        cartItemsArray.put(cartItemsObjedct);


                    }

                    dataObj.put("update_list", cartItemsArray);


                    JsonObjectRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT, url, dataObj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                Toast.makeText(_context, response.getString("status"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            //mTextView.setText(error.toString());
                        }
                    }) {
                        @Override
                        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                            headers.put("Authorization", "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Ijk5MjEyMzQ4MTMiLCJyb2xlIjoiY3VzdG9tZXIiLCJpZCI6IjU4M2VhZjI0OWM1ZDM5MTgyMzk0MTkzNyIsIm5hbWUiOiJWaWpheSBNYWxob3RyYSJ9.aF-vgNvOSSk_mbi_cTGufG2JZRrmP38zPFGn9UK9iMA");
                            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                            return headers;
                        }
                    };
                    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }


        }
    });

    notifyDataSetChanged();

    return convertView;

}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

class ViewHolder {
    EditText txtListChild;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        txtListChild = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
    }
}

public HashMap<String,List<String>> gethashmap() {

    return _listDataChild;
}
```

}

Here ,In this adapter i used gethashmap() method which call from activity so it load with fresh data but don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with following modified code :

```
        public class EditSwitch1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ExpandableListAdapter1 listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private TextView edit_text;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
    private TextView back;
    private String roomId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_editswitch1);
        pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(EditSwitch1Activity.this);
        editor = pref.edit();
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        back = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.back);
        expListView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
        // preparing list data

        Window window = EditSwitch1Activity.this.getWindow();
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(EditSwitch1Activity.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_statusbar));


        roomId = getIntent().getStringExtra("roomId");
        String serverURL = "http://dashboard.droidhomes.in/api/module?room_id=" + roomId;

        // Use AsyncTask execute Method To Prevent ANR11 Problem
        new LongOperation1().execute(serverURL);


        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter1(EditSwitch1Activity.this, listDataHeader, listDataChild, response);
        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });


    }

    private class LongOperation1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        // Required initialization

        // private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        private String Content;
        private String Error = null;

        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(
                EditSwitch1Activity.this);
        String data = "";

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

            //Dialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
            //Dialog.show();

            //         data += "Authorization:eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Ijk5MjEyMzQ4MTMiLCJyb2xlIjoiY3VzdG9tZXIiLCJpZCI6IjU4M2VhZjI0OWM1ZDM5MTgyMzk0MTkzNyIsIm5hbWUiOiJWaWpheSBNYWxob3RyYSJ9.aF-vgNvOSSk_mbi_cTGufG2JZRrmP38zPFGn9UK9iMA";
        }

        // Call after onPreExecute method
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {

            /************ Make Post Call To Web Server ***********/
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            // final String ALLOWED_URI_CHARS = "@#&=*+-_.,:!?()/~'%";
            // String urlEncoded = Uri.encode(path, ALLOWED_URI_CHARS);
            // Send data
            try {

                // Defined URL where to send data

                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);

                // Send POST data request

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                //conn.setDoOutput(true);
                String auth_token = pref.getString("auth_token", "");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", auth_token);
                //conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                //byte[] encodedPassword = ( "Authorization" + ":" + "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Ijk5MjEyMzQ4MTMiLCJyb2xlIjoiY3VzdG9tZXIiLCJpZCI6IjU4M2VhZjI0OWM1ZDM5MTgyMzk0MTkzNyIsIm5hbWUiOiJWaWpheSBNYWxob3RyYSJ9.aF-vgNvOSSk_mbi_cTGufG2JZRrmP38zPFGn9UK9iMA" ).getBytes();
                //BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();

                // Get the server response

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;

                // Read Server Response
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Append server response in string
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }

                // Append Server Response To Content String
                Content = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Error = ex.getMessage();
            } finally {
                try {

                    reader.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }

            /*****************************************************/
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

            // Close progress dialog
            // Content=Content.replaceAll("<string>","");
            // Content=Content.replaceAll("</string>", "");
            Dialog.dismiss();

            if (Error != null) {

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Bad request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                // uiUpdate.setText("Output : " + Error);

            } else {

                // Show Response Json On Screen (activity)
                // uiUpdate.setText(Content);

                /****************** Start Parse Response JSON Data *************/

                // String OutputData = "";
                // JSONObject jsonResponse;

                Gson gson = new Gson();
                // Map messageObjMap = new Gson().fromJson(Content, Map.class);
                // String type = messageObjMap.get("messageType").toString();

                // Song song = gson.fromJson(message, Song.class);

                final SearchResponse response = gson.fromJson(Content,
                        SearchResponse.class);

                if (response.getStatus() == true) {


                    List<String> newlist = new ArrayList<String>();

                    listDataHeader.clear() ;
                    listDataChild.clear();

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.getModule().length; i++) {


                        listDataHeader.add(response.getModule()[i].getModule_name());
                        newlist = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for (int j = 0; j < response.getModule()[i].getNo_of_switches(); j++) {

                            if (response.getModule()[i].getModuleId().getModuleid().equals(response.getModule()[i].getSwitches()[j].getModuleId().getModuleid())) {


                                newlist.add(response.getModule()[i].getSwitches()[j].getSwitch_name());


                            }


                            listDataChild.put(response.getModule()[i].getModule_name(), newlist);


                        }


                    }


                    //listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter1(EditSwitch1Activity.this, listDataHeader, listDataChild, response);

                    listAdapter.setListDataHeader(listDataHeader) ;
                    listAdapter.setListDataChild(listDataChild) ;
listAdapter.setSearchResponse(response) ;
                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "status:-" + response.getStatus(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }

        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }
```

> Adapter class

```
        public class ExpandableListAdapter1 extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private String childText;
    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
    private ArrayList<String> newlist;
    private ArrayList<String> newlist1;
    ArrayList<String>list1;
    private SearchResponse response;
    private Boolean onclick = true;

    public ExpandableListAdapter1(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                  HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData, SearchResponse response) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
        this.response = response;


    }

    public void setListDataHeader(List<String> list){
    this._listDataHeader = list;
    }

    public void setListDataChild(List<String> list){
    this._listDataChild = list;
    }

public void setSearchResponse(SearchResponse response){
    this.response = response;

}    

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtListChild.setText(childText); // Here whatever you will type in edittext will be overwritten by the value of 'childText.getTotal'. So after you are done writing in edit text make sore you change that in "_listDataChild" list.


        newlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        newlist1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        list1=new ArrayList<>();
        list1.add(childText);
        final TextView txtListChild1 = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.flash1);





        txtListChild1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (onclick) {

                    txtListChild1.setText("Save");
                    holder.txtListChild.setEnabled(true);
                    onclick = false;
                } else {

                    //  ArrayList<String> itemList=new ArrayList<String>();
                    //itemList.add();
                    onclick = true;
                    txtListChild1.setText("Edit");
                    holder.txtListChild.setEnabled(false);
                    newlist.add(response.getModule()[groupPosition].getSwitches()[childPosition].getSwitchId().getId());
                    newlist1.add(holder.txtListChild.getText().toString());
                    String url = "http://dashboard.droidhomes.in/api/switch";
                    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(_context);
                    JSONObject dataObj = new JSONObject();
                    try {

                        JSONArray cartItemsArray = new JSONArray();
                        JSONObject cartItemsObjedct;
                        for(int i=0;i<newlist.size();i++){

                            cartItemsObjedct = new JSONObject();
                            cartItemsObjedct.putOpt("switch_id", newlist.get(i));
                            cartItemsObjedct.putOpt("switch_name",newlist1.get(i));
                            cartItemsArray.put(cartItemsObjedct);


                        }

                        dataObj.put("update_list", cartItemsArray);


                        JsonObjectRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT, url, dataObj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                try {
                                    Toast.makeText(_context, response.getString("status"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                //mTextView.setText(error.toString());
                            }
                        }) {
                            @Override
                            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                                headers.put("Authorization", "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Ijk5MjEyMzQ4MTMiLCJyb2xlIjoiY3VzdG9tZXIiLCJpZCI6IjU4M2VhZjI0OWM1ZDM5MTgyMzk0MTkzNyIsIm5hbWUiOiJWaWpheSBNYWxob3RyYSJ9.aF-vgNvOSSk_mbi_cTGufG2JZRrmP38zPFGn9UK9iMA");
                                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                                return headers;
                            }
                        };
                        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }


            }
        });


        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        EditText txtListChild;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            txtListChild = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        }
    }

    public HashMap<String,List<String>> gethashmap() {

        return _listDataChild;
    }
```

Comment: Hello @Android dev: there is an  error in your code:- i got   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'droidhomes.droidhomes.activities.Modules[] droidhomes.droidhomes.activities.SearchResponse.getModule()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at droidhomes.droidhomes.activities.ExpandableListAdapter1$1.onClick(ExpandableListAdapter1.java:122)

Comment: Let me check , It will back with fix .

Comment: What is your line number 122 inside ExpandableList‌​Adapter1.java ? It seems the line number in my code and the code you put in your Project is different .

Comment: :Again same issue its again restore same values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141702/discussion-between-sagar-potdar-and-android-dev).

Comment: According to your code , NotifyDataSetChanged() is working now . What do you want now ?

Comment: If you got the answer , you can upvote or accept the answer as its the  worth of efforts .